# Low reading speed with ODBC Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

We have 64bit ODBC to connect from excel to an Oracle database.

We had some old servers with Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0
and now we have some new servers with oracle 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

We use the ODBC to connect an excel to the database and execute a query.
This is the connection string.
    `DSN=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;DBQ=xxx;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=20000000;TLO=0;MLD=0;ODA=F`

With the Oracle Database 11g the excel read 500,000 records in 3 minutes with the fetch buffer size parameter at 20,000,000.

But since we have changed to oracle 19c the reading data is too slow. The file read 500.000 records in 45 minutes with the same value in fetch buffer size.

Can someone help me to improve the reading speed or to understand why is happening this?

Thx.

Comment: The same data/indexes and the same execution plan?

Comment: Yes, the same. The only thing that has changed are the servers and the Oracle version.